# Count all substring that make a valid command using java

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, parsing

I am trying to make an assembly language parser, and from the given string I have to find all the valid commands. For a command to be valid, the following conditions have to be met:

1. the first letter is a lowercase English letter
2. next, it contains a sequence of zero or more of the following
   characters: lowercase English letters, digits, and colons.
3. Next, it contains a forward slash `/`
4. Next, it contains a sequence of zero or more of the following 
   characters: lowercase English letters, digits.
5. Next, it contains a backward slash `\`
6. Next, it contains a sequence of one or more lowercase English letters.

e.g. given a command `abc:/b1c\xy`

there are six valid commands:

```
abc:/b1c\xy    
bc:/b1c\xy    
c:/b1c\xy    
abc:/b1c\x    
bc:/b1c\x   
c:/b1c\x
```

I don't know anything about regular expression can someone please help me with it.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps are to be followed to solve your problem.

Step 1: We need to find all possible subsets in increasing order for the given string.
For e.g. abc  --> {a,b,ab,bc,abc} in increasing order.

Step 2: Now we have to check whether the string  you find out is following the regex pattern or not.
Credits: I am going to use the regex pattern given by Varun Chaudhary.

Step 3 : If it matches I will return 1 and keep adding count for all possible valid subsets of your string.

Step 4: Print the result.

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Main
{
    static int regexWork(String command) {

        int count =0;
        Pattern COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9:]*\\/[a-z0-9]*\\\\[a-z]+");
        Matcher matcher = COMMAND_PATTERN.matcher(command);
        //If matches returns 1
        while (matcher.find())
            count=1;

        return count;
    }


    // Finding all subsets of given set[]
    static void printSubsets(char set[])
    {
          int count =0;
          int n = set.length;
          // Pick starting point
    for (int len = 1; len <= n; len++) 
    {    
        // Pick ending point
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - len; i++) 
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            //  Print characters from current
            // starting point to current ending
            // point.  
            int j = i + len - 1;            
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) 
                sb.append(set[k]+"");

            count+=Main.regexWork(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        String set ="abc:/b1c\\xy";  //Can be any string for which you are checking
        printSubsets(set.toCharArray()); //Passing char array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use the following regex that satisfies your conditions -

```
[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9:]*\/{1}[a-z0-9]*\\[a-z]+
```

**JAVA CODE** -

```
    String command = "abc:/b1c\\xy";
    Pattern COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9:]*\\/[a-z0-9]*\\\\[a-z]+");
    Matcher matcher = COMMAND_PATTERN.matcher(command);

    while (matcher.find())
        count++;

    System.out.println("MATCH COUNT = " + count);
```

Comment: it gives the wrong answer the correct answer in 6 it return 1

Comment: will change the  " .* " part of the regex. It has to be made lazy, so the logic of the conditions will change -> instead of zero or more a-z before the forward slash it'll become something like "anything apart from forward slash and then forward slash"